# RSpec: Using a each loop for similar it blocks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I am writing tests to check if certain end-points return a status of 200.

```
RSpec.describe 'API -> ' do
  before do
    @token = get_token
  end

  describe 'Status of below end points should be 200 -->' do

    it "/one should return a status code of 200" do
      get("/api/v1/one", params: {
        authentication_token: @token
      })
      expect(response.status).to eql(200)
    end

    it "/two should return a status code of 200" do
      get("/api/v1/two", params: {
        authentication_token: @token
      })
      expect(response.status).to eql(200)
    end

    it "/three should return a status code of 200" do
      get("/api/v1/three", params: {
        authentication_token: @token
      })
      expect(response.status).to eql(200)
    end

  end
end
```

There are many such end points and i wanted to know if there is more efficient way to write this, something like

```
RSpec.describe 'API -> ' do
  before do
    @token = get_token
    @end_points = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
  end

  describe 'Status of below end points should be 200 -->' do
    @end_points.each do |end_point|
      it "/#{end_point} shold returns a status code of 200" do
        get("/api/v1/#{end_point}", params: {
          authentication_token: @token
        })
        expect(response.status).to eql(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but this does not work and gives an error `each called for nil`.

Any help with this will be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use is a [shared example](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

```rb
shared_examples "returns 200 OK" do |endpoint|
 let(:token) { get_token }

 it "should return a status code of 200" do
   get(endpoint, params: { authentication_token: token })
   expect(response.status).to eql(200)
 end
end

describe '..' do
  include_examples 'returns 200 OK', '/api/endpoint/1'
  include_examples 'returns 200 OK', '/api/endpoint/2'
end
```

Comment: This is 100% the way to go. In my opinion shared examples are a highly under utilized component of RSpec (especially for API tests). In a previous project I managed to condensed the testing of CRUD logic for 47 different models into 1 set of shared examples (with nested shared examples) eliminating thousands of lines of testing code that was especially copy and paste in different contexts. If a standard pattern exists for tests in multiple files shared examples are by far the best way to keep your testing clean and consistent

Answer (score 1):

[John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68651543/125816) is good, especially if you have more specs per endpoint.

As to your attempt, it was a simple mistake with scoping. Your instance variable is set on one level, but used on another. Set it on the same level.

```rb
  describe 'Status of below end points should be 200 -->' do
    end_points = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    end_points.each do |end_point|
      it "/#{end_point} shold returns a status code of 200" do
        get("/api/v1/#{end_point}", params: {
          authentication_token: @token
        })
        expect(response.status).to eql(200)
      end
    end
  end
```